# How to setup a finger specific app launch?

Tags: fingerprint, 9.0-pie

On my ZTE Axon 7 I had four fingers configured to start specific apps when the corresponding finger was pressed. That was very practical to be able to start an app like Evernote directly. On that device that could be specified in the setting and that setting seems to be missing on Pixel 3.

Is there a way to do something similar on the Pixel 3 (with Android Pie)? (It's even okay if I have to write code.)

Comment: Are you using Android 8 or 9? For Android 8, there is an Xposed module which might suffice as an alternative to your requirement. See https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-fingerprint-action-pro-quick-t3724493

Comment: Also Gravity Box Xposed module can be used